# Internal card reader and motherboard have differently sized internal USB connectors

Tags: usb, motherboard, connector

I'm trying to install an internal SD card reader in my computer. However, it seems like the plugs are different, so the internal USB cables I have don't fit.

Here is the motherboard (Gigabyte Z97X-UD5H) plug:

[image]

Here is the card reader's (TEAC CA-200) port:

[image]

On the ruler, top is cm. By counting pixels and neglecting parallax, I determined that the pins on the motherboard are 0.094 inch or 0.24 cm apart, while on the card reader they are 0.079 inch or 0.20 cm apart. Seems like the pin layout is also different, but it has the same number of pins.

How can I get this card reader to work?

Comment: Did it come with any cables?

Comment: @Steve It din't.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that this particular card reader uses a non-standard port.

According to a [forum thread](http://pinouts.ru/forum/index.php?topic=2797.0) I found, the TEAC-200:

> However, the Teac CA-200 Flash Card reader has a non standard 10 pin configuration (Flexbay connector 2.00 mm apart vs. 2.54mm apart).

Sounds pretty close. The same thread has the correct pin scheme, so it might be possible to just wire a DIY connector, but I abandoned that idea after realizing that I can just buy a [new one on Amazon for $12](http://amzn.com/B00D2NMTB0).